# Sharepoint custom workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have created SharePoint custom form how to make the custom form as default in the SharePoint designer. I have already done with  my coding for designing the form but I need to know how to make this custom form as default in the sharepoint.

Comment: Try https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com for faster help

Answer (score 1):

In Sharepoint Designer go to the desired list where you made custom forms (Site -> Lists & Libraries -> YourCustomList.  In the Forms window on the right, select the form you created, then in the ribbon on the top there's a button for "Set as Default".